# I am having trouble with reading input from a file into a structure of arrays

Tags: c, codeblocks

here is the problem i am having. basically the structure is defined properly, but the compiler is throwing out an error when it tries to read input from the given file. I can get through the menu in the while loop before the case and then do option 'a' or 'A' and get the patient number. Then I can open the file but I cannot read any information from the file into the structure variables. it just terminates the code. The files I am trying to read in from are formatted as follows:
time   BP_diastolic   BP_systolic
01     80             120
02     81             124
03     78             118
etc.

time   temp
01     98.7
02     99.0
03     98.5
etc.

time   rate
01     68
02     70
03     65
etc.

I am supposed to read info in from the files, put them into variables and then determine the health score for a given day according to this equation:
(,,,) = 15∗+35∗+25∗ +25

where: 
 temp is based on the body temperature at time t, and is defined as:   = {1    97 ≤  ≤ 99 0  ℎ
  press is based on the blood pressure at time t, and is defined as: 
 = {
1    ≤ 80   ≤ 120                   0.5   80 <  ≤ 89  120 <  ≤ 139 0    ≥ 90   ≥ 140
  rate is based on the heart rate ending at time t based on some ∆t, usually 15 to 60 seconds, and is defined as:  = {1  60 ≤  ≤ 100 0 ℎ

I have not gotten to that section yet as I can't figure out how to get the info into the variables. Therefore I am not able to do any calculations with said data.

If option d) is chosen, the program should ask the user for a time point to calculate the Health Score.  After entering a valid time (i.e. should be within the given time interval), the program should display: 
a. a table with the values for BT, BP, and HR, 
b. a report on the detection of any conditions (i.e., normal / prehypertension / 
   hypertension) described above, and 
c. the HealthScore value obtained using Eq. 1.

If option e) is chosen, a table with the statistical parameters (over the time interval) for each variable should be displayed. This includes the Min, Max, Avg, and Standard Dev.

There should also be tests done to ensure all entries to the program are within the proper range.

I hope this is a better explanation of the problems I am having. Also, at this point the assignment is late but I would still like to understand what I am doing wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>


    struct bloodPressure{
       int time;
       double pressD;
       double pressS;
    };

    struct temp{
       int time;
       double temp;
    };

    struct rate{
       int time;
       double r;
    };

    struct bloodPressure BP[55];
    struct temp T[55];
    struct rate R[55];
    int main()
      {
            int timeStart,
                timeEnd,
                timeSelect;
          double minTemp,
                 maxTemp,
                 avgTemp,
                 stdTemp,
                 minPressD,
                 maxPressD,
                 avgPressD,
                 stdPressD,
                 minpressS,
                 maxPressS,
                 avgPressS,
                 stdPressS,
                 minRate,
                 maxRate,
                 avgRate,
                 stdRate,
                 score;
          char fileName[140],
               fileNameBuffer[150],
               patientNum[5],
               menuSelect = "a";
          FILE *fp;



          while (menuSelect)
          {
             printf("Please select from the following list:\n");
             printf("a/A: Enter patient number\n");
             printf("b/B: Enter file folder location\n");
             printf("c/C: Enter time interval\n");
             printf("d/D: Get health score\n");
             printf("e/E: Get statistical data\n");
             printf("f/F: Exit the program\n");
             scanf("%c", &menuSelect);

             switch(menuSelect)
             {
                // code to enter patient ID number
                case 'a':
                case 'A':
                {
                   // ask user for the patient's ID number
                   printf("Please enter the Patient's ID number:\n");
                   scanf("%s", &patientNum);

                   printf("%s", patientNum);

                   // break out of switch statement and return to main                 
                   // menu
                   break;
                }

                // code to enter file location
                case 'b':
                case 'B':
                {
                   printf("Please enter the file location:\n");
                   scanf("%s", &fileName);

                   // if file for blood pressure does not open, display 
                   // error and return to main menu
                   sprintf(fileNameBuffer, "%sBP_%s.txt", fileName, 
                   patientNum);
                   fp = fopen(fileNameBuffer, "r");
                   printf("%s \n", fileNameBuffer);
                   if (fp == NULL)
                   {
                      printf("cannot open file");
                   }

                   // if file opens, read information from the file
                   // else
                   {
                      printf("file is being read\n");
                      // read in variables from blood pressure file into 
                      // blood pressure structure
                      while (!feof (fp))//int i = 0; i < 55; i++)
                      {
                         int i = 0;
                         fscanf(fp, '%d %lf %lf', BP[i].time, 
                         BP[i].pressD, BP[i].pressS);
                         printf("%d", BP[i].time);
                         if (++i >= 55)
                         {
                            break;
                         }
                      }

                      // close the blood pressure file
                      fclose(fp);
                   }

                   // if file for blood temperature does not open, display 
                   // error and return to main menu
                   if (fp = fopen(("%sBT_%d.txt", fileName, patientNum), 
                   'r') == NULL)
                   {
                      printf("cannot open file");
                   }

                   // if file opens, read information from the file
                   else
                   {
                      // read in variables from heart rate file into blood 
                      // pressure structure
                      while (!feof (fp))
                      {
                         int i = 0;
                         fscanf(fp, '%d %lf', &(T[i].time), &(T[i].temp));
                         if (++i >= 55)
                         {
                            break;
                         }
                      }

                      // close the heart rate file
                      fclose(fp);
                   }

                   // if file for heart rate does not open, display error 
                   // and return to main menu
                   if (fp = fopen(("%sHR_%d.txt", fileName, patientNum), 
                   'r') == NULL)
                   {
                      printf("cannot open file");
                   }

                   // if file opens, read information from the file
                   else
                   {
                      // read in variables from heart rate file into blood         
                      // pressure structure
                      while (!feof (fp))
                      {
                         int i = 0;
                         fscanf(fp, '%d %f', &(R[i].time), &(R[i].r));
                         if (++i >= 55)
                         {
                            break;
                         }
                      }

                      // close the blood pressure file
                      fclose(fp);
                   }

                   // break out of switch statement and return to main 
                   // menu
                   break;
                }

                // code to enter time interval
                case 'c':
                case 'C':
                {
                   // ask user for start and end times for the time 
                   // interval
                   printf("Please enter the starting time:\n");
                   scanf('%d', timeStart);
                   printf("Please enter the ending time:\n");
                   scanf('%d', timeEnd);

                   // break out of switch statement and return to main 
                   // menu
                   break;
                }

                // code to calculate health score
                case 'd':
                case 'D':
                {

                   break;
                }

                // code to calculate statistical data
                case 'e':
                case 'E':
                {

                   break;
                }

                // code to exit the program
                case 'f':
                case 'F':
                {
                   printf("You have chosen to exit the program\n");
                   exit(1);
                }

                default:
                {
                   printf("Error: Please enter a valid menu option (a-f or 
                   A-F)");
                   break;
                }
             }
          }



        return 0;
      }
```

Comment: What is the input file format? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Who or what text suggested `while (!feof (fp))`?

Comment: In `&BP[i].time, ...` `i` is not defined, nor limited.  Post a [mcve]

Comment: `fscanf(fp, "%d %f %f", &BP[i].time, &BP[i].pressD,  &BP[i].pressS);` should be more like `BP sample; ... fscanf(fp, "%d %f %f", &sample.time[i], ...`  Yet your overall goal is unclear.

Comment: I'm not sure how to add my entire code. I only added a sample of the code in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

#### Edited after question was changed -- see below

---

Quite a few things in your code would not be accepted by compilers - here are some improvements you could make:

1. Strings need double quotes in C, so `"` instead of `'`
2. Variables should be declared before use. In your code, for instance, `fp` and `fileName` were not declared, and `BP` was declared as a type-alias (with `typedef`) instead of a variable.
3. There were a few minor mistakes, like commenting out the `else` statement and not ending the if-part of that condition with a brace `}`.
4. `fopen()` does not accept the construction for the filename you gave it - you must first do that in a separate function call to `sprintf()`.
5. My compiler wasn't too thrilled about the construction `if (fp = fopen(...) == NULL)`, though perhaps other compilers may accept it. The statement can be split.
6. In the `fscanf()` statement, there were three things:

   - The indexes `[i]` were in the wrong places,
   - `i` was not defined and didn't get increased to the next value, and there was no check on it reaching its maximum value
   - Minor point: to read values of type *double*, you'd use the scan string `%lf` (long float).

C is a pretty hard language when you start, so don't worry... Here is what I made of it (which worked correctly on my computer):

```
#include <stdio.h>

// structure definitions
struct bloodPressure{
    int time[55];
    double pressD[55];
    double pressS[55];
};

// declarations
struct bloodPressure BP;
char fileName[100], fullname[110];
int i = 0;
const int patientNum = 1;
FILE *fp;

// start of problem
int main() {
    printf("Please enter the file location:\n");
    scanf("%s", fileName);
    sprintf(fullname, "%sBP_%d.txt", fileName, patientNum);

    // if file for blood pressure does not open, display error and 
    // return to main menu
    fp = fopen(fullname, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("cannot open file");
    }

    // if file opens, read information from the file
    else
    {
        // read in variables from blood pressure file into blood 
        // pressure structure
        while (!feof (fp))    //int i = 0; i < 55; i++
        {
            fscanf(fp, "%d %lf %lf", &(BP.time[i]), &(BP.pressD[i]), &(BP.pressS[i]));
            if (++i >= 55) break;
        }
        // close the blood pressure file
        fclose(fp);
    }
}
```

You might consider changing the definition of `struct bloodPressure` so it holds pressure data of *one* measurement, and then create an array of such structs, like

```
struct bloodPressure BP[55];
```

instead of what you have here, a struct holding arrays. It seems more logical to me.

---

### EDIT

As you have rewritten your question and your program (and improved it a lot I think), I'm editing the answer.

> I can open the file but I cannot read any information from the file into the structure variables. it just terminates the code.

In line 109, your `fscan` scanning pattern is still single-quoted (quotes should be `"`). Same in some other places, like line 188.

By the way, your `else` statement in line 101 is still commented out.

Generally your coding is improving fast. It might help if you tell your compiler to warn you when you do something that may lead to errors. Many compilers accept an option `-Wall` (**W**arn at **all** things it doesn't like).